# Comparing Two Uneven Matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

Please assume `A` is a reference matrix:

```
A = zeros(6,6); A([2 3 6] , 1:3) = 2; ; A([1 4:6] , [5 6]) = 2;A(6 , 3) = 0; 
A(5 , 6) = 0; A(2,2)=0
```

Means:

```
A =
     0     0     0     0     2     2
     2     0     2     0     0     0
     2     2     2     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     2     2
     0     0     0     0     2     0
     2     2     0     0     2     2
```

Then, how we can find indices of members that are matched with `B` pattern:

```
B = 2 * ones ( 2 , 3); B ( 1 , 2 ) = nan
```

Which the pattern is:

```
B =
         2   NaN     2
         2     2     2
```

The result should be like:

```
C1 = 
       [  2 ,  1   
          3 ,  1 
          3 ,  2
          2 ,  3
          3 ,  3 ]
```

and

```
C2 = 
       [  4 ,  5   
          4 ,  6 
          5 ,  5
          6 ,  5
          6 ,  6 ]
```

In `C1` and `C2`, first column is the rows and the second column is columns of indices:

```
CN =  [ Rows , Columns ]
```

Please find the image that is attached. thanks[image]

Comment: What if there are overlapping regions? What is the output for `[2,2,2,2; 2,2,2,2; 2,2,2,2; 2,2,2,2]`? Will it be the indices of all elements?

Comment: Are `A` and `B` always going to be either `2` or `0` or can `B` have multiple values that have to match the same values in `A`?

Comment: Also, can `NaN` match anywhere? So what I mean is if there is a `NaN` value at a position in `B`, then that position can be matched to any value in `A`. Am I right? I think `blockproc` with a custom function handle will do the job. The drawback is that you will have to rotate `B` and do everything again. However, you will be able to make use of `parfor`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin the result should consider all possible answers even for more than one overlap. Thanks

Comment: @Suever A and B include only two integer values (like 0 and 1).

Comment: @Iman That wasn't my question. Basically are there only two values in `A` and `B` or can they have `N` different integers.

Comment: @Suever yes. Only two values.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar instead of `NaN`, we can use `0`. It means only `2` are matter here. not `0` or `NaNs`